# PHP Cart - Adding variables

Tags: php, mysql, cart

I am creating a PHP cart for a photography business. This is the 1st Ecommerce site I have attempted (Newbie)

I have managed to add products to the cart (stored in the session)
(Products: Print, Keyring, Magnet ect)

However I also need to add the imageID to the session

Here is my code

```
$product_id = $_GET[id];     //the product id from the URL 
    $imageId = $_GET[imageid];   //the image id from the URL 
    $action     = $_GET[action]; //the action from the URL 

    switch($action) {   //decide what to do 

        case "add":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        break;
```

Which saves the product to the basket
[image]

The cart.php url is shown as:

> cart.php?imageid=83&id=12&action=add

Could anyone help/advise how I add the Image ID to the product?

Thanks

Comment: By _"add the Image ID to the product"_ do you mean store it in the session or display the image in the basket?

Comment: Can you show the code which generates the basket mark-up then?

Comment: Normally the product would be stored in a database table by the product id, which would in turn store the image path. There would then be no need to pass the image id. The product id would be the key to all information related to the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming one image can be used by different products? Otherwise, you should simply be able to deduce which image to use based on the product ID:

```
case "add":
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id
    $_SESSION['images'][$product_id] = $imageId; //Will map the image ID to the product being added
break;
```

Anyway, without seeing your actual markup, adding the image to the basket should be something like:

```
<basket element>
    <item element>
        <img src="path/to/images/<?=$_SESSION['images'][$product_id]?>.filetype" />
    </item>
</basket>
```